# How to get value of input control outside of a form without submitting it?

Tags: javascript, php

I spend almost an hour googling it but i found nothing helpful,
Here's my code

```
<div class = "form-group col-md-12">
    <input type="text"  name="filename" id="filename"></input>
</div>
```

Its outside the form, what i want to do is that what i type there should be put here

```
 $fopen=fopen( $uploadpath.here.'.png','wb');
```

So i can manage the filename thus it wont be static.

Comment: You need to use `ajax` to get the value without submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to send the data to your back-end code (php) as it won't run once it comes to browser. If I'm right, you want to open the file in your back-end but your page might get reload, so you want to not submit the form. If this is the case you can use ajax, like this:

```
<div class = "form-group col-md-12">
    <input type ="text"  name = "filename" id="filename"></input>
</div>
<script>
var filename = $("#filename").val();
$.ajax({
    url: myfile.php, //url to your php file with code  $fopen=fopen( $uploadpath.here.'.png','wb');
    type: post,
    data: {"fileName":filename},
    success: function(result) {
        // use your code to handle the result whatever you want to do here
    }
})
</script>
```

Your php file

myfile.php

```
<?php
$uploadPath = $_POST['fileName'];
$fopen=fopen( $uploadpath.here.'.png','wb');
echo "success"; // you can return whatever you want and that will go to success function in your javascript

?>
```

Comment: it says undefined index

Comment: change `data: {"fileName":fileName},` to `data: {"fileName":filename},`

Comment: actually what i  wanted in here is im going to concatenate another declared $filename    to the word (here)  `$fopen=fopen( $uploadpath.here.'.png','wb');`

Comment: Do this => `$middleNamePath = $_POST['fileName'];
$fopen=fopen( $uploadpath.$middleNamePath.'.png','wb');`

Comment: Sir do i need to put a button to pass the ajax ?

Comment: The AJAX function you habe used is of core javascript, which shall also work. I have used jquery here, if you are using jquery, then better go this way. As far as button is concerned, that depends when do you need to make the call. If, the button click is not required, then no need to put the button.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ajax $.post it's much easier

```
<div class = "form-group col-md-12">
    <input type ="text"  name = "filename" id="filename"></input>
</div>
<script>
var filename = $("#filename").val();
$.post("yourfile.php", {"fileName":filename}, function(data) {
    // do something
})
</script>
```

your php

```
<?php
    $uploadPath = 'youruploadfolder'; // this is the location of your file folder
    $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];  // this is your file passed via ajax request
    $fopen = fopen($uploadpath.$fileName.'.png','wb');
    echo "success"; // you can return whatever you want and that will go to success function in your javascript
?>
```